# Error with delayed job. Couldn't Parse YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, yaml, delayed-job

I'm passing a csv file to delayed job via the following code.

```
csv_text = IO.read(params[:emails_import].tempfile.to_path, :encoding => 'UTF-8').gsub(" ", "")
csv_text = csv_text.gsub("\n\n", "\n")
Delayed::Job.enqueue ImportContact.new(@list.id, csv_text), :queue => "import-list-#{@list.id}"
```

I am receiving the following error message via foreman. Any idea what could be causing this issue? I think the error might be in the csv file, but im not sure where / what is causing the problem.

```
[Worker(host:ubuntu pid:22678)] Starting job worker
16:50:22 worker.1 |   SQL (129.4ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET locked_at = '2013-04-16 20:50:22', locked_by = 'host:ubuntu pid:22678' WHERE (id = 121 and (locked_at is null or locked_at < '2013-04-16 16:50:22') and (run_at <= '2013-04-16 20:50:22'))
16:50:22 worker.1 |   SQL (96.4ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET locked_by = null, locked_at = null WHERE (locked_by = 'host:ubuntu pid:22678')
16:50:22 worker.1 | rake aborted!
16:50:22 worker.1 | couldn't parse YAML at line 6709 column 4
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:84:in `payload_object'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:71:in `name'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `handle_failed_job'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:191:in `block in run'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:191:in `rescue in run'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:181:in `run'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:238:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:238:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:166:in `block in work_off'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `times'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `work_off'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:133:in `block (4 levels) in start'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:132:in `block (3 levels) in start'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in start'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:128:in `loop'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:128:in `block in start'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:127:in `start'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/gems/delayed_job-3.0.3/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
16:50:22 worker.1 | /home/cory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@postpourri/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
16:50:22 worker.1 | Tasks: TOP => jobs:work
16:50:22 worker.1 | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
16:50:22 worker.1 | exited with code 1
16:50:22 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Comment: Why pollute your database with such massive amounts of csv data? If it's coming to you as uploaded files, why not leave it in that format and let the job you're queuing up do the conversions before passing it into the `ImportContact` instance? Do you have the same problem when running the job independent of delayed_job/the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this code in a brand new Rails app with Delayed::Job installed (modified from what you provided):

```
class List
  attr_accessor :id
end
@list = List.new
@list.id = 123

class ImportContact
  def initialize(list_id, csv_text)
    @list_id = list_id
    @csv_text = csv_text
  end

  def perform
    puts @list_id
    puts @csv_text.length
  end
end

csv_text = IO.read('test_2000_import_contacts.csv', :encoding => 'UTF-8').gsub(" ", "")
csv_text = csv_text.gsub("\n\n", "\n")
Delayed::Job.enqueue ImportContact.new(@list.id, csv_text), :queue => "import-list-#{@list.id}"
```

When I ran `bundle exec rake jobs:work`, everything went through correctly, which would lead me to believe that there is a problem with the way YAML is encoding or decoding the file you are importing.

In particular, I would run

```
yaml = Delayed::Job.find(121).handler
File.open('job-121.yml', 'w') { |f| f.write(yaml) }
```

And check through the file around `line 6709 column 4`.

However, this might be about the time to suggest that you store your files in something like S3 and pass a URL to the `ImportContact` worker rather than the entire CSV text. This will alleviate the current problem you are running into and help you avoid bloating your database with huge text columns.

Comment: This was useful in debugging the problem. I ended up slicing the csv files into smaller pieces, which helped reduce deserialization issues.